# Sound not coming from video in video tag in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use a video with sound in the video tag but the sound is not playing when I run it in browser ,if I remove the `muted` attribute video doesn't play .The video directly works in browser if you open the link.Please help

```html
  <div class="background-wrap">

      <video preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted>
            <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type="video/mp4">  </video>

           </div>
```

Comment: You can not autoplay a video unless it is muted in most browsers these days.

Comment: so how to unmute it?? while it is played?

Comment: Let me quote Turnip: "You can not"

Comment: so that means I can never play a video with sound in browser ? @ChrisG

Comment: You can either: a) autoplay muted video or b) wait for the user to click play, then play with sound (the idea is to prevent a situation where a user visits a site and sounds starts blaring from the speakers without warning; in other words the situation you describe and are looking to overcome is deliberately in place)

Comment: Change autoplay attribute to false.